# SAS: How to loop through a dataset replacing a (large) list of strings read from a column in another data set?

Tags: loops, sas

Firstly, I have rudimentary SAS skills at best so please forgive me is this is a daft question.

Essentially I have a large free text field I need to redact by removing names and replacing with a "[NAME REDACTED]" placeholder.

The list of names to be replaced is 412k obs long (i.e. I can't manually type out the list) so I need to refer to them in the column in the data set where they're stored.  This data set appears in the form:

```
ID    Name
1     Jim
2     Steve
3     Susan
4     Karen
```

The below is a rough idea of what I'm looking to do (though of course does not run) with the "SELECT NAME from LIB.NAMELIST.Name" being the part that I don't know how to reference.

```
data=have;
set=want;
nstart=1;
nfinish=412000;
do while(nstart<=nfinish);
TRANWRD(DescriptionField,(*SELECT NAME FROM LIB.NAMELIST.Name WHERE ID = 
nstart*),"[NAME REDACTED]");
nstart+1
;
END
;
```

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Comment: If `John` is on your list of names, do you also need to redact minor typos and variations that might occur in the free text field? E.g. `john`, `jon`, `Kohn` etc? How cautious do you need to be here?

Comment: Also, is each name a single word, or do you have `Firstname Lastname` entries in a single field, or separate fields for first and last names?

Comment: Hi both, it is just literally the list contained in LIB.NAMELIST in the NAME column that need to be redacted from DescriptionField in Have, no other variations are required.

Comment: P.S.  If it's of any relevance, Have has 5000 obs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this, using a temporary array to hold the list of names:

```
data name_list;
  input ID  Name $;
  datalines;
1     Jim
2     Steve
3     Susan
4     Karen
;
run;

data have;
  input text $100.;
  infile datalines truncover;
  datalines;
Jim AAA
Steve Susan BBB
Susanne CCC
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into :n from name_list ;
quit;

data want;
  set have;
  array names[&n] $8 _temporary_;
  if _n_ = 1 then do i = 1 to &n;
    set name_list(keep = name);
    names[i] = name;
  end;
  do i = 1 to &n;
    text = tranwrd(text,strip(names[i]),'[NAME REDACTED]');
  end;
 keep text;
run;
```

You may also wish to consider what you want to do about the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) if you adopt this sort of approach.

Comment: I don't understand what's missing. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it, that's incredible helpful - really shows my ignorance in SAS that I was completely unaware that you can separately set more than one dataset within a data step to reference.  (Apologies for the confusion, I started typing a comment without reading through the answer properly).